# Custom allocator for STL priority_queue

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I am trying to pass a custom allocator to STL's `priority_queue`. I've been able to do so for STL's `vector` and `unordered_map`, but cannot use similar syntax for `priority_queue`. Anyone has a hint or sample code I can use?

Note that I need to pass an instance of the allocator as one of the constructor's arguments.

Thank you

Comment: Note that e.g. `std::vector` and `std::unordered_map` are actual containers. [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is a [container *adaptor*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Container_adaptors) which uses other containers in specific ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `std::vector` and `std::unordered_map`, which are containers, `std::priority_queue` is a container adaptor. It contains a container and provides special access it to. Looking at suitable [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), you can see that the second template parameter of `std::priority_queue` is a container (`std::vector` by default). So you just need to pass your own container with a custom allocator:

```
std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T, MyAllocator>> q;
```

Comment: It worked with a minor modification: `std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T, MyAllocator>, std::less<T>> q(compare, container);`

Comment: Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 0):

`std::priority_queue` is a container adaptor. It doesn't allocate anything by itself, it defers that to the underlying container (which, by default, is `std::vector` with the default allocator). See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

In other words: To use a custom allocator, you have to specify a container (probably `std::vector`) that uses your custom allocator as the `Container` template argument of `std::priority_queue`. Then you can use any of the `std::priority_queue` constructors that accepts an allocator instance.